# eclipse mars can't start on windows 7

Tags: java, eclipse

guys, there is a problem with eclipse.exe. When I tried to start it, eclipse start picture appeared and then after 1 second it disappeared. I don't see any errors or messages and some useful info. Can anyone help me?

Comment: make sure JAVA_PATH variable is set and java version >= 7 and try opening it through command-prompt.

Comment: "guys, there is a problem with eclipse.exe. " no there isn't, works just fine on my windows 7 machine. I'm afraid its a you-problem, you can make it everyone's problem by blaming the tools. So since it is a you-problem, the question would need you-details to be able to answer anything. Eclipse.ini, the Java installation you have (version, architecture), which Eclipse distribution did you download, etc. etc. The devil is in the details.

Comment: I would like to expand on @Gimby: The obviously wrong assumption that there is a general problem with eclipse out of the hybris that it can't be a problem by you is one thing. But treating peers of which you expect a well thought out and readable answer *for free* with a lack of any respect whatsoever is a totally different one. I strongly suggest to put more effort in your questions and your wording. "Lackey, u solve this!" won't attract many people willing to help. Be thankful for those good souls who are trying to help you.

Comment: @Markus W Mahlberg, Gimby, Thank you for helpful tips, I will take this into account further

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I don't mind being expanded upon, but I didn't see any disrespect here myself. "Can anybody help me?" is a support request (and thus off-topic), not a work order :)

Comment: @Gimby I was *seconding* that is agreeing with you... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the logs, there's a .log file in the .metadata directory inside each workspace, if there is a crash during startup it could be found there. Another possibility is to start eclipse with these arguments

```
 -clean -clearPersistedState
```

OR you could stop the splashscreen from showing (if the crash would be causes by the splashscreen itself)

open eclipse.ini and remove the line

```
 -showsplash
```

then add

```
  -nosplash
```

Because it could be caused by the splashscreen. I would say make sure your java home etc is set up correctly, but with my experience with eclipse, it would show you an error message if this is the problem.

Comment: The problem was in wrong PATH variable which pointed to old jdk1.7.0_60